# how to use Indexed hint Option Query

Tags: java, mongodb

I have a collection on which i have a index on a filed named symbol .

I have read the benefeies of using hint on a query which reduces speed of the query

```
db.collection.find({"symbol" : "RESD"}).hint( { symbol: 1 } )
```

Could anybody please tell me how can i use Indexed hint Option Query   with java , right now this is my code .

```
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
query.put("symbol", symbol);
DBCursor cursor = coll.find(query);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

`DBCursor cursor = coll.find(query).hint(new BasicDBObject("symbol" , 1))`

Answer (score 2):

With new (3.x) drivers you need to specify $hint:

```
private static void testHint(MongoDatabase db) {
    MongoCollection<Document> col = db.getCollection("Stores");
    FindIterable<Document> iterable = col.find(new Document("store","storenumbervalue"));
    iterable.modifiers(new Document("$hint","index_name"));
    MongoCursor curs =  iterable.iterator();
    while(curs.hasNext()){
        System.out.println(curs.next());
    }        
}
```

index_name - actual index name in mongo.